# Fix the separator as just one white space while reading a .txt file

Tags: r

How do I fix the separator as just one white space as opposed to the default one or more white spaces, while reading a .txt file in R using *read.table()* function? The fields are not of fixed width.

Following are the two rows of the table, in the first row, there are two spaces after ***1300***, the first is a separator, the second being a missing value. I have to account for the missing value too.

```
11000110101 110001101   07  G4D 64  102 1   2   202 20  12  12  02  4   1   2012    11000   1   1   01  01  1300        443.5   887 2   4   88700
11000110102 110001101   07  G4D 64  102 1   2   202 20  12  12  02  4   1   2012    11000   1   1   01  02  190     443.5   887 2   4   88700
```

Comment: You should be able to solve that with `sep = " "`. However, your data is not as described. The first line has the same number of columns as the second (no missing values). There are multiple spaces after each column.

Comment: @JBGruber has probably already solved the problem. i will just offer a different idea using the `sub(pattern="   ", replacement= " ", data)` 3 spaces added in first sub() argument and 1  space to the replacement

Comment: @JBGruber In the actual file, one space is a separator, the next is a missing value. I had inserted the two rows as code for easy readability. And `sep = " " ` doesn't solve it, it just read the whole row as one element.

Comment: Your separator is tab, not space. read.table with defaults should work fine.